# Define the generic type of a generic function after using typeof

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Look at the following example:

```
function test<T>(a: T[]) {return a};
type testReturnType = ReturnType<typeof test> // typescript infers type unknown[]
```

Is there a way to parameterize the generic type `T` of  `testType`, so that I can choose `T`?
I wish to do something like:

```
type testReturnType<A> = ReturnType<typeof test<A>>
```

Where typescript would infer the type of `testReturnType<A>` to be `A[]` and therefore I could do something like:

```
function anotherFunction(b: testReturnType<number>) {..}
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Not possible at present there is no syntax to specify generic type parameters to a generic function when using `typeof`

Comment: If you provide more details about your needs we might be able to suggest an alternative solution that doesn't require using `typeof`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sadly there is no pure TypeScript way of doing this :(

However you can work around your issue like this:

```
// First let's create a type signature for the test function
type TestFunction<T> = (params: T[]) => T[];

// Then the function itself
function test<T>(a: T[]) {
  return a;
}

// At this point you could say okay, I will just always make sure that test()
// is of type TestFunction. OR: You can bind them together!
// Since you cannot 'assign' a type to a function in TypeScript
// and you can't have generic const either you have to use a little trick:
const assertTest = <T>(): TestFunction<T> => test;

// The assertTest will just make sure that the signature of test()
// and the TestFunction type match. (you don't actually need to call it anywhere in your code)

// Then you can create your return type helper easily:
type TestReturnType<T> = ReturnType<TestFunction<T>>;
```

You can then try doing sillier things with your `TestFunction` type and see that the code still works:

```
type TestFunction<T> = (params: T[]) => T extends string ? number : T[];

// ...

type A = TestReturnType<string>; // A will be number
type B = TestReturnType<{}>; // A will be {}[]
```

Hope that helps!